# Add a second UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have my first NavigationController set up with root viewcontroller - PhotoViewController, It's a collectionView with grid of images. When image is selected I wan't to present a second navigationController with root controller - DetailViewControler.

My first navigationController is set up in appDelegate. I really don't understand how and where should I create the second. I'm not using IB. At the moment I have this in my DetailViewcontroller viewDidLoad:

```
    DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
self.detailController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailView];
```

But when i'm trying to push a new controller, nothing happens. I guess that my code is in wrong place.

When I try to present second controller modally from my PhotoViewController, I have an error(trying to present nil viewController).

Comment: why do you want to present a second navigation controller? Why not present the detail view after selecting an image so that pressing back will get you back to the PhotoViewController?

Comment: I'm building this app purely for learning purposes. I just wan't to learn how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

The common idea is to have a single navigation VC that contains -- and lets you navigate between -- other VCs.  In the situation you describe, you wouldn't create another navigation VC.  Instead, create just the detail VC and push that onto the existing navigation VC...

```
// assuming self is a view controller contained by a navigation controller
self.detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailController animated:YES];
```

Comment: So multiple navigationControllers is a bad practise? I'm presenting detailVC modally using `[self.navigationController presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];` but when I try to push something onto detailVC, example, commentVC, it doesn't work -  `CommentViewController *commentView = [[CommentViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:commentView animated:YES];` Is it even possible to push something on after view is presented modally, in same controller? I've done this in past using IB and multiple navigationVC.

Comment: Not always a bad practice.  If you have a master view, and want to present a detail view, then push onto the master's existing nav vc is good.  If you're starting a brand new flow, then a "modal" push of a brand new nav vc (with a new root) is okay.  But that second case is more rare, and your situation sounds more like master-detail.

Comment: Thanks, my case was the second one. Forgot to mention that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent view controller as your initial view controller and add the navigation controllers as children, then transition between them. See this blogpost that I wrote: http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/container-view-controllers-parent-view.html